# Using pgr_drivingDistance with large ids

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2po

I have little experience with postgres and none with pgrouting.

I'm trying to use the `pgr_drivingDistance` function with Open Street Map data (generated through `osm2po`), but whenever I run my query:

```
SELECT pgr_drivingDistance('SELECT id, osm_source_id::int4 AS source, osm_target_id::int4 AS target, cost::float8 AS cost FROM nyc_2po_4pgr', 85, 2, false, false);
```

I get `ERROR:  integer out of range`—I assume because some of the osm_source_ids I'm getting in don't fit in an `int4`. Is that what's going on?

I'm using a small subsection of the OSM data, so I assume I could squash the source_ids/target_ids into an `int4` range. How would I do that?

Alternatively, is there a way to make the `pgr_drivingDistance` work with the larger source/target ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osm_source_id::int4` casts an 8-Bytes-Long-Integer down to a 4-Byter. Hence the error message is correct. Anyway, `osm_source_id` is the wrong attribute. Use `source` (target) instead.